# X,Y position of semi cylinder - ray - triangle- intersection to space [-1,1] [-1,1]

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, raytracing

I am rendering a tile map to a fbo and then moving the resulted buffer to a texture and rendering it on a FSQ. Then from the mouse click events, I got the screen coordinates and move them to clip space [-1,1]:

```
    glm::vec2 posMouseClipSpace((2.0f * myCursorPos.x) / myDeviceWidth - 
                 1.0f, 1.0f - (2.0f *  myCursorPos.y) / myDeviceHeight);
```

I have logic on my program that based on those coordinates, it selects a specific tile on the texture.

[image]

Now, moving to 3D, I am texturing a semi cylinder with the FBO I used in the previous step:

[image]

In this case I am using a ray-triangle intersection point that hits the cylinder with radius r and height h.  The idea is moving this intersection point to space [-1,1] so I can keep the logic on my program to select tiles

I use the Möller–Trumbore algorithm to check points on the cylinder hit by a ray. Lets say the intersected point is (x,y) (not sure if the point is in triangle, object or world space. Apparently it's worldspace). 
I want to translate that point to space x:[-1,1], y[-1,1].

I know the height of my cylinder, which is a quarter of the cylinder's arc length:

cylinderHeight =  myRadius * (PI/2);

so the point in the Y axis can be set in [-1,1]space:

```
vec2.y = (2.f * (intersectedPoint.y - myCylinder->position().y) ) / 
         (myCylinder->height()) - 1.f
```

and That works perfectly.

However, How to compute the horizontal axis which depends on 2 variables x and z?

Currently, my cylinder's radius is 1, so by coincidence a semi cylinder set in the origin would go from (-1 ,1) on the X axis, which made me think it was [-1,1] space, but it turns out is not.
My next approach was using the arc length of a semi circle **s =r * PI** and then plug that value into the equation:

```
vec2.x = (2.f * (intersectedPoint.x - myCylinder->position().x) ) / 
             (myCylinder->arcLength()) - 1.f
```

but clearly it goes off by 1 unit on the negative direction.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Isn't that more a math than a programming problem?

Comment: How can the intersection point be 2D if a cylinder is 3D? Do you mean the parametric coordinates (named `u, v` or `s, t` in many implementations) that Möller–Trumbore calculates?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Well, the intersection point is between a ray and a triangle part of the cylinder, so indeed it has 3 coordinates. But, I was able to translate the Y coordinates to [-1,1], how to do it with the horizontal axis when it depends on 2 variables?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I asked in the math stackexchange forum , but no help there. I wanted to give it a try on this one

Comment: There are 3 axes in 3D. If you define "vertical" to be the Y axis, then there are **two** "horizontal" axes - X and Z. You might be confusing 3D space with screen space. Perhaps include a diagram and give sample  coordinates.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it seems that you want to convert the world space intersection coordinate to its corresponding normalized texture coordinate.

For this you need the Z coordinate as well, as there must be **two** "horizontal" coordinates. However you *don't* need the arc length.

Using the relative X and Z coordinates of `intersectedPoint`, calculate the polar angle using `atan2`, and divide by `PI` (the angular range of the semi-circle arc):

```
vec2.x = atan2(intersectedPoint.z - myCylinder->position().z,
               myCylinder->position().x - intersectedPoint.x) / PI;
```

Comment: It works !!  I had tried using atan2, but I never dived by PI (noob issues). Because my cylinder is located at the negative z - axis, I had to swap the coordinates in you equation and multiply by 2 because the frame buffer object width is twice as large as the original viewport.

Comment: @Camilo ah ok, might be a different normalization scheme (happens a lot in graphics programming)